# Send base64 string image to form input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base64

I have a plugin which crops my image and sends back a base64 data that looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...`

Question is how can I send that data to my file input field? If I do `$("input#file").val(img);` where `img` is my base64 string I get `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Comment: not possible. file inputs are heavily restricted in what you can do with them, and allowing code to override what gets uploaded would be a major security risk.

Comment: The question is "why would you want to set a file input field to a base64 encoded string"??? Sounds like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Are you trying to store the file as a base64? i.e. the user is uploading an image?

Comment: yea the user is uploading the file after it has been cropped and sent to us in a base64 form

Answer (score 3):

you can not set the value of a file input field . There may be other alternatives such as setting the base 64 value to a hidden input field and then submitting the form.

Comment: hidden input field is different than normal file input? Can I upload the image stored in base64 that way?